# How to change font color of disabled input in Firefox

Tags: html, css, firefox

When I disable input elements the text is taking the font color: `#000000` in Firefox. This is not happening in IE. Please check the below page in IE and Firefox. Let me know how to give it a gray look as in IE.
[test](http://shivanand.in/tmp/test.html)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Different browsers style disabled elements differently.  Here is how you can control the style of disabled elements in Firefox.

```
[disabled] {
  color:#ff0000;
  background-color:#00ff00;
}
```

Comment: I tried your style, it is taking bg color green and not font color

Comment: @Shivanand: works if you write it with !important: color:#ff0000 !important; @ng.mangine: good trick!

Comment: how the F do i do this in IE8?

Answer (score -1):

Reenable it, change the color, disable it again. It will only take .001 seconds.